# How to get a <td> Text from code behind in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `<td>` that contains text.

```
<td width="60%" id="SpeciesName" runat = "server" ><b><%#showData(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></b></td>
```

I am trying to get the innertext of `SpeciesName' from the code behind, and Add it in a String list. I was capable of doing so for`asp:Textbox`, but not for``.

here is the code behind in vb.net

```
 Private Shared Function getInputValues(ByVal currItem As RepeaterItem) As List(Of String())

    Dim Input As String = "SpeciesName"
    Dim alParams As New List(Of String())(1)

                Dim txtCurrent As TableCell = CType(currItem.FindControl(lstInput), TableCell)
                If txtCurrent.Text.Trim <> "" And txtCurrent.Text.Trim <> "0" Then
                    alParams.Add(New String() {Input, txtCurrent.Text.Trim, "int"})
                End If
       Return alParams
    End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the innertext of `SpeciesName`? i.e. this part, right - `<b><%#showData(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></b>`?

Comment: @TheUknown exactly!

Comment: @TheUknown I just solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I just solved this, there were two problems with this. 1) the `txtCurrent` should be declared as an HtmlTableCell not a TableCell.

2) it's the innertext I should be getting not the text.

here is the the updated code behind:

```
Private Shared Function getInputValues(ByVal currItem As RepeaterItem) As List(Of String())

    Dim Input As String = "SpeciesName"
    Dim alParams As New List(Of String())(1)

                Dim txtCurrent As HtmlTableCell = CType(currItem.FindControl(lstInput), HtmlTableCell)
                If txtCurrent.InnerText.Trim <> "" And txtCurrent.InnerText.Trim <> "0" Then
                    alParams.Add(New String() {Input, txtCurrent.InnerText.Trim, "int"})
                End If
       Return alParams
    End Function
```

Comment: plus 1 for figuring a solution to this yourself